# Input a sequence of numbers in a Fortran list

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am facing the following problem:

I want to loop over a specific sequence of numbers e.g.

1 3 4 6 7 9 10 .... 528

I have thought a way to do it but I am not so familiar with fortran. The idea is to create a list with the numbers which are not in the sequence:

```
B=(/2 5 8 11 .... 527/)
```

and deduce this list from another one with all the numbers

```
A=(/1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ..... 528/)

C=A-B
```

What I was thinking is something like:

```
program test

  implicit none

  integer, dimension(6)  :: A
  integer, dimension(10) :: B
  integer                :: i, j

  A = (/ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ..... 528/)
  B = (/ 2 5 8 11 .... 527/)

  C=A-B

end program test
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If yes how can I deduce two lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-` isn't a set complement operator, so `C=A-B` doesn't return an array (which you haven't declared) consisting of the values in A not in B.

However, you don't need to do this for your desire:

```
do i=1, 528
  if (....)  ! i not in B
  ....
end do
```

Of course, the tricky part is in the `if` condition.  However, if B is sorted:

```
j = 1
do i=1, 528
  if (i.eq.B(j)) then
    j = j+1
    cycle
  end if
  ...
end do
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `A` and `B` as in your question you could first declare an array of `logical`s and set all its elements `.true.`, *ie*:

```
logical, dimension(size(A)) :: themask = .true.
```

Then the expression

```
themask(B) = .false.
```

will set to `.false.` all the elements of `themask` in the index vector `B` and

```
C = pack(A,themask)
```

will return, in `C`, only those elements of `A` for which the corresponding element in `themask` is `.true.`.  For this to work you will have to have declared `C` like this:

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: C
```

and be using a Fortran 2003-compliant compiler which allows automatic allocation.  Most of the current widely used compilers do implement this feature.

If you have no use for `A` other than for holding a list of `N` integers, you can just work with a temporary along the lines of

```
C = pack([(ix, ix = 1,N)],themask)
```

where `ix` is a previously-declared integer. This expression -- `[(ix, ix = 1,N)]` -- uses an *implied-do* loop to populate the temporary vector.

You can now loop over the values of `C` if that is what you want to do, but maybe you want to use `C` as a vector index into another rank-1 array, such as `D(C)`.

No fiddling around with loops here but I make no claims that this approach will perform better (or worse or different) than the loop-based suggestion from @francescalus.